# Capacitor DUE board 10uf polarized?

Tags: arduino, pcb

I found in the schematics of Arduino DUE some polarized capacitor but in the board I can see NO polarized capacitor.

Somebody to know why ?

[image]

I guess the capacitor on board is like a capacitor 50v like [Capacitor Murata](https://octopart.com/grm32df51h106za01l-murata-196602?r=sp&s=m7XteoYoRnODj3AzcUqrSg)

Comment: Also, considering the amount of Arduino clones (and the duplication of the respective documentation online), are you sure that schematic refers to that exact board?

Comment: Thanks. I have a board 95% exact

Answer (score 4):

> Somebody to know why ?

Only the guy who drew the schematic.

Most likely, they were just sloppy about what symbol they use for these things in their schematics.

It's conceivable that they designed the thing years ago to use polarized capacitors, but changed to ceramics when 10 uF became affordable in an appropriate package.

> I guess the capacitor on board is like a capacitor 50v like Capacitor Murata

That's only a 5 V power line (unless they're using some newish USB power delivery system that provides higher voltage), so it could very well be a 10 or 16 or 25 V rated part.

Comment: Thanks very much